# Error while installing bottle for python 2.7 on windows machine

Tags: python, bottle

I have installed python 2.7, pymongo 2.3 and setup tools for python 2.7 on my windows machine(32 bit). But while installing bottle, I am getting an error and the screenshot of which is attached here. Could you guys help me out solving this??

[image]

Comment: **Please** don't post screenshots of text. It's text: post it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing *bottle* using **pip** instead.
If you don't already have pip installed:

- Download pip
- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
- Run the pip installer

  python get-pip.py
- install bottle using pip

  pip install bottle